# Memory efficient method to compute sqrt of large matrix with negative values

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sqrt

I need to compute sqrt of a large matrix with positive and negative numbers. The problem is since sqrt is sensitive to sign. So I am using the following code.

```
neg=numpy.argwhere(temp<0)
temp=numpy.abs(temp)
temp=numpy.sqrt(temp)
temp[neg]=-temp[neg]
```

In this code, first I am storing locations of negative values and then computing square root after converting to positive and later on append negative sign to them. The issue is it gives memory error in the first statement.

Is there any alternative memory and computationally efficient method to achieve same task. The size of matrix is of the order of `O(10^5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with large data, we can also use [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) that supports multi-core processing if the intended operations could be expressed as arithmetic ones. The caveat is we need to use arithmetic vectorized operations. So, an arithmetic solution for our problem would be -

```
(2*(temp>=0)-1)*np.sqrt(np.abs(temp))
```

Porting this to `numexpr` is pretty straight-forward -

```
import numexpr as ne

ne.evaluate('(2*(temp>=0)-1)*sqrt(abs(temp))')
```

#### Benchmarking

Original function -

```
def orgfunc(temp):
    neg=temp<0
    temp=numpy.abs(temp)
    temp=numpy.sqrt(temp)
    temp[neg]=-temp[neg]
    return temp
```

Timings on large arrays -

```
In [55]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: m,n = 1000,1000
    ...: temp = np.random.randn(m,n)

In [56]: %timeit orgfunc(temp)
100 loops, best of 3: 16 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit ne.evaluate('(2*(temp>=0)-1)*sqrt(abs(temp))')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.47 ms per loop

In [58]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: m,n = 10000,10000
    ...: temp = np.random.randn(m,n)

In [59]: %timeit orgfunc(temp)
1 loop, best of 3: 2.09 s per loop

In [60]: %timeit ne.evaluate('(2*(temp>=0)-1)*sqrt(abs(temp))')
1 loop, best of 3: 248 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm surprised that numexpr doesn't have a `sign` function.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yup! Could be a good addition to their list.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy "where" is a suitable alternative for your problem, Try this code:

```
result = numpy.where(a>=0, numpy.sqrt(a), -numpy.sqrt(-a))
```

This line of code returns sqrt of the numbers in your matrix if it is positive or zero, otherwise returns negative of negative sqrt.